# How to manually abort a Python3 script in Spyder3 with Keyboard

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder, keyboardinterrupt

How to manually `abort/stop` (I call this KeyboardInterrupt) the execution of a Python3 script, using Spyder??

When I click `run file` or `run current cell`, nothing can stop the execution of a script until it is finished.

Python 3.7.0 64-bit, Qt 5.9.6, PyQt5 5.9.2, Spyder 3.3.4, Anaconda 3 64bit, Windows 10 64bit

`Ctrl + C` doesn't work,  `Ctr+X` doesn't work,   The red "stop the current command" button in IPython console doesn't work.
The only way I can stop a running script is by menu Consoles> Restart kernel.

This example code shows that KeyboardInterrupt doesn't work in Spyder, 
in none of the 3 sections below.

```
@author: xynxnex'''

#%% 
def hello():
    print('Hello Spyder '+str(nr))
import time
nr = 0
while nr < 42:
    nr +=1
    hello()
    time.sleep(1)    

#%% loop in function
def hello(n):
    nr = 0
    while nr < n: #n is a local variable, thus not shown in Variable explorer
        nr +=1 #nr is a local variable, thus not shown in Variable explorer
        print('Hello Spyder '+str(nr))
        time.sleep(1)
    return n
import time
x = hello(42) #

#%% just a simple loop
import time
nr = 0
while nr < 42:
    nr +=1
    print('Hello Spyder '+str(nr))
    time.sleep(1)
```

No errors, but the loop just keeps on executing until it is finished.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl c  (not capital c) produced the keyboard interrupt for me.  Spyder 3.3.6
Python 3.6.8 64-bit | Qt 5.9.6 | PyQt5 5.9.2 | Windows 10

```
#%% just a simple loop
    import time
    nr = 0
    while nr < 42:
        nr +=1
        print('Hello Spyder '+str(nr))
        time.sleep(1)

Hello Spyder 1
Hello Spyder 2
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-23-b2c4320912d9>", line 7, in <module>
    time.sleep(1)

KeyboardInterrupt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `CTRL + D` it will work,  if you run out of all the options.